# Query with QProcess

Tags: c++, qt, pipe, qtcore, qprocess

I'm supposed to check whether the service is `RUNNING`. I've a problem with `QProcess` query execution, when it comes to executing the following query: `SC QUERY "service name" | findstr RUNNING`, though this works fine when executed directly in command line in Windows. The code snipet here as follows:

```
    QProcess process;
    process.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedChannels);
    process.start("SC QUERY \"Service_name\" | findstr RUNNING", QIODevice::ReadWrite);


    // Wait for it to start
    if(!process.waitForStarted())
        return 0;

    QByteArray buffer;
    while(process.waitForFinished())
        buffer.append(process.readAll());
    qDebug() << buffer.data();
```

Output is: [image]

Can you help me?

Comment: What problem exactly? Have you checked the stdout/err with the object as well as the errorString()? Also, show your code!

Comment: It doesn't execute it, but rather refers to help command

Comment: Please show your code how you are trying to use it. Are you sure you are piping it correctly? Which Qt are you using, just in case, etc? Check this: http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qprocess.html#setStandardOutputProcess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because using these three lines will not give you the expected results:

```
QProcess process;
process.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedChannels);
process.start("SC QUERY \"Service_name\" | findstr RUNNING", QIODevice::ReadWrite);
```

Based on the [official documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#setStandardOutputProcess), `QProcess` is supposed to work for pipe'd commands:

> void QProcess::setStandardOutputProcess(QProcess * destination)
>
> Pipes the standard output stream of this process to the destination process' standard input.

In other words, the `command1 | command2` shell command command can be achieved in the following way:

```
QProcess process1;
QProcess process2;

process1.setStandardOutputProcess(&process2);

process1.start("SC QUERY \"Service_name\"");
process2.start("findstr RUNNING");
process2.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedChannels);

// Wait for it to start
if(!process1.waitForStarted())
    return 0;

bool retval = false;
QByteArray buffer;
while ((retval = process2.waitForFinished()));
    buffer.append(process2.readAll());

if (!retval) {
    qDebug() << "Process 2 error:" << process2.errorString();
    return 1;
}

qDebug() << "Buffer data" << buffer;
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer Laszlo, but there is no output?

Comment: @elgolondrino: do you get output in the console? Have you checked errorString() if there are any errors?

Comment: No there is no error output just an empty (QByteArray) buffer

Comment: @LaszloPapp I think you should add `process2.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::ForwardedChannels);`, otherwise the output of the second process will not be shown.

Comment: @elgolondrino: try to add the one-line back I used from your original code. Does it work then?

Comment: Great, np. Thanks go to @UmNyobe spotting one issue in my code. :)